# Программное создание типизированного JPA репозитория

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Работаю со Spring boot и Hibernate. В проекте присутствует много сущностей. Чтобы получить объекты этих сущностей из БД для каждой из них создается типизированный JPA репозиторий.

```
@Repository
public interface OrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}

@Repository
public interface OrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<Organization, Long> {
}

@Repository
public interface OrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
}
```

Есть ли возможность получать бины нужных JPA репозиториев программно в runtime'е, не создавая для них отдельных репозиториев? Т.е. создать фабрику, которая по предоставленному типу сущности создаст репозиторий для этой сущности.

```
public <T, ID> JpaRepository getRepository(Class<T> tClass, Class<ID> idClass) {
    ...
    JpaRepository<T, ID> jpaRepository = ... **магия**
    return jpaRepository;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь [SimpleJpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html):

```
class RepositoryFactory {
  @Autowired
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public <T, ID> JpaRepository<T, ID> getRepository(Class<T> tClass) {
    return new SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>(tClass, entityManager);
  }
}
```

Использование:

```
RepositoryFactory repoFactory = ...;
JpaRepository<Customer, Long> customerRepo = repoFactory.getRepository(Customer.class);
```

Comment: `JpaRepository<T, ID> jpaRepository = getRepository(tClass);`

`System.out.println(jpaRepository.findAll().size());` //Отрабатывает

`jpaRepository.save(entity); `//Генерирует ошибку: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call

Comment: Это не имеет отношения к созданию репозитория. Методы любого репозитория можно вызывать только внутри транзакции. Пометьте метод, в котором вызываете `save` аннотацией `@Transactional`

Comment: Работает! Спасибо!